# Accessing only the ids of a objectbox ToMany relation

Tags: java, android, objectbox

When accessing the elements of an objectbox ToMany (without backlink) relation the database is queried for the elements.
Is there a faster method to only access the ids without querying its entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is (currently) not for a ToMany that is not a `@Backlink` to a ToOne.

This could be part of a feature request to make editing ToMany possible without loading all entities.
https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/510

For completion: if the ToMany **is** a `@Backlink` to a ToOne one can query for the related entities where the ToOne ID property is equal to the entity owning the ToMany. An example:

```
@Entity class Customer {
    @Id long id;
    @Backlink(to = "customer") ToMany<Order> orders;
}

@Entity class Order {
    @Id long id;
    ToOne<Customer> customer;
}

long[] orderIds = orderBox.query()
    .equal(Order_.customerId /* virtual property */, customer.id)
    .build()
    .findIds()
```